# Using JNIEnv::FindClass: do I need to free the returned jclass reference?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

Suppose I have this code in a JNI function that implements a `native` function stub:

```
JNIEnv* env; /*This is set to a valid JNIEnv* for this thread*/
jclass clz = env->FindClass("foo"); /*this has worked*/
```

Do I need to call

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(clz);
```

once I'm done with it? I'm not returning `clz` back to Java so I'm thinking that I need to delete the local reference? It seems a little odd though since like a `MethodID`, a `jclass` doesn't contain an object instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to call `DeleteLocalRef`.
`FindClass` returns a local reference. So there is no need to delete. The JVM will do this automatically after the JNI call is finished.
But if you want you can delete the local reference. It should not make any difference.

Comment: There are a limited (but configurable) number of local references available. So, the best practice is to delete if the reference is created in a loop. [Ref](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~kloukin/IN2P3/material/jni.pdf)

Comment: @TomBlodget you have a better reference besides the entire JNI manual? `DeleteLocalRef` expects a `jobject`. Are you sure one should cast something like `jclass` to a `jobject`?

Comment: @HeShiming `jclass` can be cast to `jobject`, as it's subclassed from it: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/include/jni.h#L68 (note that JNI is also specified as C API, but also there a `jclass`'s data begins with `jobject`, so it can be type-cast, and the C side of `jni.h` has `typedef jobject jclass;`).

Answer (score 8):

It is never wrong to call `DeleteLocalRef`, so you should always call it, otherwise you could run into situations where the number of local references is used up.

When your JNI code is called from Java, and it's short-running, you might be lucky enough that the local references get cleaned up for you after you return to the Java caller, but if you e.g. call into the Java VM from native code (so there's no "outer" Java VM frame from which your JNI code is called), then you will quickly use up your local variables, because they will never be deleted by a non-existent Java caller.

To quote the [official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects):

---

In most cases, the programmer should rely on the VM to free all local references after the native method returns. However, there are times when the programmer should explicitly free a local reference. Consider, for example, the following situations:

- A native method accesses a large Java object, thereby creating a local reference to the Java object. The native method then performs additional computation before returning to the caller. The local reference to the large Java object will prevent the object from being garbage collected, even if the object is no longer used in the remainder of the computation.
- A native method creates a large number of local references, although not all of them are used at the same time. Since the VM needs a certain amount of space to keep track of a local reference, creating too many local references may cause the system to run out of memory. For example, a native method loops through a large array of objects, retrieves the elements as local references, and operates on one element at each iteration. After each iteration, the programmer no longer needs the local reference to the array element.